# WPF Open a Modal window from UserControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, modal-dialog

I have a MainWindow in my WPF app.

This MainWindow has a menu on the left and when a menu option is selected a UserControl is loaded on the right.
This is similar to Master Pages in asp.net

What I want to do now is to have a modal window show from the UserControl which will only allow the user to interact with the modal window.

I have seen examples of the Main Window showing a modal window (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36516/WPF-Modal-Dialog) but not sure on how to load this from a UserControl.

Answer (score 1):

There's this: [dialogs and mvvm](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36745/Showing-Dialogs-When-Using-the-MVVM-Pattern) but this is the best example I've seen of dealing with it: [mvvm and closing forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/413517/Closing-Windows-and-Applications-with-WPF-and-MVVM)

The first link I've not used and stumbled across while looking for the second link to post that here. The second link has two downloads, you can ignore the _service download, it's basically the same.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I had a quick look at it and was wondering would this help me if I have a user control that needs to open a Modal window.

Answer (score 0):

One way in WPF is this method

1. Add a new `Window` to the project.
2. Add other controls onto the window as needed.
3. In XAML name the window such as `x:Name="MyWindow"`
4. Put on Dependency properties on the window and have each of the controls bind to the window's data context such as `{Binding MyText, ElementName=MyWindow}`. (Note I still use, even for WPF these Visual Studio code snippets to add different dependency properties, these save time for a very redundant operations of adding them: [Silverlight Snippets](https://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/02/silverlight-snippets/).
5. In the location where you want to launch the model dialog use this example:

Example:

```
 var about = new About(); // Create the new window

 // I've added a CompanyName dependency property.
 about.CompanyName = "OmegaMan Industries";

 about.ShowDialog();
```